# TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined. Dialog Material Angular

Tags: angular

I'm making a dialog and I have an error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
at AppComponent.openDialog (app.component.ts:53)

Here's the line 53: `const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);`
Here's the code:

```
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
    
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
        });
    }
```

I added to app.component.ts

```
import { DialogComponent } from '../dialog/dialog.component';
```

In module.ts

```
import { DialogComponent } from './pages/dialog/dialog.component';
```

I added MatDialogModule to imports
entryComponents: [ DialogComponent ] and i also declared DialogComponent.

idk why I have an *ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
at AppComponent.openDialog (app.component.ts:53).*

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Please share how you have injected the dialog in your app component.Can you share plunker of your code.

Answer (score 5):

```
    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog){}
```

Make sure that you injected MatDialog in place where you use it.
In your case its AppComponent`s constructor